# How to get key of array when i know this value in php

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
$array = array('name'=>'Van Pham','age'=>'23','sex'=>'male');
```

How can I get key '**age**' with value '**23**'?

Comment: You know its key or its value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for `array_keys` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

```
print_r(array_keys($array, "23")); // age
```

OR by **HamZa DzCyberDeV**

```
echo array_keys($array, "23")[0];
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/bZErGT

Comment: Or just `echo array_keys($array, "23")[0];`

Answer (score 1):

use [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
$key= array_search($value, $array);
```

example:

```
$array = array('name'=>'Van Pham','age'=>'23','sex'=>'male');
echo array_search("23", $array); //age
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$my_arr = array('name'=>'Van Pham','age'=>'23','sex'=>'male');

echo get_array_by_value($my_arr, '23');

function get_array_by_value($my_arr = '', $arr_value = '') {
  $new_arr = array_flip($my_arr);
  if (isset($new_arr[$arr_value])) {
    return $new_arr[$arr_value];
  }
}
```

output

```
age
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $array = array('name'=>'Van Pham','age'=>'23','sex'=>'male');
    echo array_keys($array, "23") .":". $array['age'];
?>
```

**Output**

```
age : 23
```

Comment: I corrected your code, and you're still returning the "wrong" code, this will drop an error since `array_keys()` will return an array, and to echo a value of an array you have to specify the index of it's value ...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
    $arr = array('name'=>'Van Pham','age'=>'23','sex'=>'male');

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to find the keys, for values 23, do it like this:

```
$array = array('name'=>'Van Pham','age'=>'23','sex'=>'male');

while ($value = current($array)) {
    if ($value == '23') {
        echo key($array)."\n";
    }
    next($array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily using `array_search` function.This Function **Searches the array for a given value** and returns the corresponding **key** if successful.

```
<?php
$array = array('name'=>'Van Pham','age'=>'23','sex'=>'male');
$key1 = array_search('23', $array); 
echo '<p>Key 1='.$key1.'</p>';
$key2 = array_search('Van Pham', $array);
echo '<p>Key 2='.$key2.'</p>';
$key3 = array_search('male', $array);
echo '<p>Key 3='.$key3.'</p>';
$key4 = array_search('female', $array);
echo '<p>Key 4='.$key4.'</p>';
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Key 1=age

Key 2=name

Key 3=sex

Key 4=
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pzbPqL)**

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
   if($key == 'age' && $value == '23')
       echo $key.'-'.$value;
}
```